# best way to duplicate teeChart to ReportBuilder for printing purposes

Tags: teechart, reportbuilder

I have a TeeChart with 32 series and 6 custom axes. I need to print this chart, and we're using ReportBuilder everywhere else in our software to print charts (where there will be a printpreview on the screen first). We're using the CloneChart-method to have the Chart copied to ReportBuilder. With this chart we have the problem that the chart is not fully visible, like it is not stretching. 
I also notice that the custom axes are not visible in ReportBuilder. 
My goal is to have an exact copy of the TeeChart on the form, in ReportBuilder for printing purposes.

I tried copying the custom-axis, added the custom-axis in the ReportBuiled ppChart. Point is that the series are created at runtime. Hmmm, I need to link the series with the right custom axes or something. 
I tried several other things in a search for streching, without success.

```
    for i := 0 to aChartSource.SeriesCount - 1 do
    begin
      if aChartSource[i].Active then
      begin
        s := CloneChartSeries(aChartSource[i]);
        s.ParentChart               := AChartTarget.Chart;
        s.GetVertAxis.Grid.Visible  := (s.GetVertAxis.Grid.Visible and aShowGrid);
        s.GetHorizAxis.Grid.Visible := (s.GetHorizAxis.Grid.Visible and aShowGrid);
        s.Marks.Visible             := (s.Marks.Visible and aShowMarks);
        s.OnGetMarkText             := GetMarkText;

        for ii := 0 to AChartSource[i].Count -1 do
        begin
          if (s.ValueColor[ii] <> AChartSource[i].ValueColor[ii]) then
          begin
            s.ValueColor[ii] := AChartSource[i].ValueColor[ii];
            vRedraw := TRUE;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

```
    { Duplicate the axis }
    for i := 0 to aChartSource.CustomAxes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      ppchrtKPI.Chart.CustomAxes.Add;
      LAxis.
      LAxis := ppchrtKPI.Chart.CustomAxes[ppchrtKPI.Chart.CustomAxes.Count-1];
      LAxis.Assign(aChartSource.CustomAxes[i]);
    end;
```

The ouput on the ReportBuilder's PrintPreview form is a chart with the series, but without the custom vertical axes. And the Teechart in ReportBuilder seems to be cropped; the series near the bottom X-axis are not visible

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://www.steema.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17241), the problem with the custom axes sounds like the ticket [#780](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=780) which was fixed in v2018.24.180321.